# Transitioning from Using Jar to Dependency for Ion

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ion

I originally had ion-1.3.8.jar in my libs directory in Android Studio, with `compile files('libs/ion-1.3.8.jar')` in my build.gradle file. I also had (and still have) androidasync-1.3.8.jar in my libs folder and an entry for it in build.gradle.

I want to get rid of the ion jar and instead use a dependency, but when I delete the jar and put `compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+` in my build.gradle file, I get an error ("cannot resolve method get(String...))" on the following line of code in one of my classes: `result.getHeaders().get("USER-TOKEN");`.

I'm guessing that line of code probably wasn't what it should have been all along, but it did work with Ion 1.3.8. I can't figure out what I should change it to, and though I can probably figure it out with some trial and error, I would like to hear from the community or Koush about this.

Also, Android Studio is warning me that "Avoid using + in version numbers; can lead to unpredictable and unrepeatable builds". Any thoughts about this?

Here's my code:

```
Ion.with(activity)
            .load(url)
            .setJsonObjectBody(loginObject)
            .asJsonObject()
            .withResponse()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<JsonObject>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, com.koushikdutta.ion.Response<JsonObject> result) {
                    String errorText = activity.getString(R.string.unable_to_login);
                    if (e != null) {
                        String errorMessage = e.getLocalizedMessage();
                        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
                        if (errorMessage.contains(activity.getString(R.string.unable_resolve_host))) {
                            errorText = activity.getString(R.string.no_internet);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (result != null) {
                        JsonElement reply = result.getResult().get(activity.getString(R.string.user));
                        if (reply != null) {
                            errorText = NO_ERROR;
                            SessionManager.setProfile(result.getResult());
                            String userToken = result.getHeaders().get(activity.getString(R.string.user_token));
                            SessionManager.createLoginSession(userToken);
                            if (SessionManager.isProfileComplete()) {
                                activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, NavigationDrawerActivity.class));
                            }
                            else {
                                activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, ProfileActivity.class));
                            }
                        }
                        else if (result.getResult().getAsJsonArray(activity.getString(R.string.errors)) != null) {
                            errorText = activity.getString(R.string.login_error);
                        }
                    }
                    else { // There was some other problem logging in
                        Log.e(TAG, "Unknown login problem");
                    }
                    requestCompleted.onRequestCompleted(errorText);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

On version 2.+ of ION the API probably changed.

If you want to use the old API that works with your code, change your dependency to: 
`compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:1.3.8'` 
It will also automatically add the Android Async 1.3.8 dependency for you.

The warning saying that you should avoid the '+' is because that way, gradle will always get the newest version it finds, where some APIs can change and then break your code.

Comment: Yes, that does work, though it would be nice to use 2 and be able to tell gradle to use the latest version of that (i.e., specify the "+"), but I'm seeing why that's dangerous, as apparently the API has changed and broken my code. I'll probably just stay with 1.3.8, though I'll wait a bit to accept this to see if Koush weighs in. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The API changed slightly in 2. One of those was changing the names of a few methods around the ResponseFuture and RawHeaders classes. In your case, getHeaders() was simply renamed to headers().

The transition from 1.x to 2.x is fairly painless, but there are some breaking changes nonetheless.

If you don't want to deal with the breaking changes, and use the latest version of 1.x in gradle, do the following:

compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:1.+

There are no breaking changes between 1.x versions. Current 1.x version is 1.4.1 I believe.

Comment: Thanks. It's easy for me to change getHeaders() to headers() (I'm only using it in a couple places), but I am a bit concerned about future changes breaking other things. However, my preference generally is to use the newer library. If I want to avoid ".+" for 2.x, is there a way to know what the current version is? (I assume you can tell me, but if there's a way at any point in time to look it up, that may be useful). Also, is the readme at GitHub up to date? getHeaders() still seems to be shown there.

Comment: I tried to use headers() with the Ion 2.x, and I get a message saying headers() is not visible outside its package. My apologies if I'm a clueless newb, but I don't think I know how to make this work. I can still go back to 1.x, but I'd like to understand what's going on in my attempt to use 2.x. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the full code? Will update the README.

Comment: I've posted my code. Please let me know if you'd like anything else.

Comment: result.getHeaders().headers().get(...) ought to work

Comment: Tried result.getHeaders().headers().get(...), but still says headers() is not public, cannot be accessed from outside its package.

Comment: Finally figured out that result.getHeaders().getHeaders().get(...) works (at least so far).